# 301 Redirect from Magento to new store

Tags: apache, .htaccess, magento, redirect, http-status-code-301

I have a magento store set up at `www.mysite.com/store/` - this is a Magento store and I want to redirect everything to a new domain `www.mysiteshop.com`.

I've put a `.htaccess` in the root of the Magento directory so that anyone who comes to it get redirected to the new store domain.

I don't need to redirect visitors who come to `www.mysite.com`.

`RewriteRule (.*) http://www.mysiteshop.com/$1 [R=301,L]`

But I need to make some changes as to how it works.

First, if they visit `www.mysite.com/shop/alarm-clock.html` I need to redirect them to `www.mysiteshop.com/products/alarm-clock`.

I also want to still be able to access the old admin area so if I could not redirect the url `www.mysite.com/shop/index.php/admin/`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your htaccess file with the mysiteshop.com rule is *in the `/store/` directory*, then you'll need to create another htaccess file in the document root (this is where you end up if you go to `http://www.mysite.com/`) in order to handle redirects for `/shop/`:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/shop/index\.php/admin
RewriteRule ^shop/(.+)\.html$ http://www.mysiteshop.com/products/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Or, you can place the rules in the htaccess file in the `/shop/` directory:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/shop/index\.php/admin
RewriteRule ^(.+)\.html$ http://www.mysiteshop.com/products/$1 [L,R=301]
```